# Where did she stay?

Tags: geography, letter-sequence

1. In `1968`, she went to **Vientiane**. She stayed 1 year

   - Then she went to **Ulaanbataar**. She stayed 8 years
2. In `1977`, she went to **Wellington**. she stayed 8 years
3. In `1990`, she went to **Stockholm**. She stayed 2 years

   - Then she went to **Lomé**. She stayed 2 years
4. In `1994`, she went to **Washington D.C**. She stayed 1 year

   - Then she went to **Hanoi**, for 2 years.

She was born in **Tirana** in `1950`, she lived 50 happy years.

## Where?

Where did she live in `1986`?

## When?

How long did she stay?

---

Inspired by this: [She went... She stayed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86132/9385)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1986 she lived in

> Muscat

She lived there for

> 3 years (1985-1988)

Reasoning

> For each letter of the alphabet, in order, she lives in the capital city of a country beginning with that letter for a number of years equal to the number of U.S. states beginning with that letter.
>  For example, she was born in Tirana, **Albania** and lived there for 4 years because there are 4 U.S. states beginning with the letter **A**.
>  After living in Wellington, **New Zealand**, she would then move on to the capital city of a country beginning with **O**, the only one of which is **Oman**, and live there for 3 years because there are 3 U.S. states beginning with the letter **O** (Oregon, Ohio, Oklahoma).

Slight issue

> I think there is a slight deviation in the question and answer because, by my reckoning she would arrive in Vientiane, **Laos** in 1967 (rather than 1968) but everything else fits so well that I assume this to be a typo (and anyway leads to the same answer).